# How to run Opendds application without test_run.pl perl script?

Tags: visual-studio, ace, opendds

I am using VS2017,

Eclipse 4.4 modeling SDK, transport is TCP

I created a model and generated code from it, now able to run the application publisher.cpp and subscriber.cpp with test_run.pl Perl file from Opendds GitHub ([common Perl file](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/tools/modeling/tests/Messenger/run_test.pl)), but as I know this for testing purpose only,

I have pub.exe and sub.exe

how to run them without Perl script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the OpenDDS lib directory is in your PATH, after that you can execute the pub and sub.

Comment: Does RTPS support tcp?

Comment: OpenDDS supports TCP as transport, see the OpenDDS dev guide for more details, see http://download.objectcomputing.com/OpenDDS/OpenDDS-latest.pdf

Comment: how to set paths in Visual Studio? I mean all the environmental variables paths which are in setenv.cmd?

Comment: You can set them in your system settings or open the Developer Tools command prompt, run setenv and after that run devenv from the command prompt, it will get the environment variables set by setenv